# Elasticsearch получить ранжирование значение поля по уникальным записям

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

В **Elasticsearch** получить ранжирование значение поля по уникальным записям.

Индекс содержит записи о прыжках спортсменов. Попыток у одного спортсмена может быть множество.

Структура документа:

```
{
   'event_at' : '2015-01-01T12:12:10', - дата прыжка
   'user_id' : 2142, - id спортсмена
   'distance' : 4 - результат
}
```

Необходимо получить выборку:

```
{
  'distance_range' : {
    '*-5' : 12, - кол-во уникальных спортсменов у которых максимальный прыжок от 0 до 5. 
    '6-10' : 14, - кол-во уникальных спортсменов у которых максимальный прыжок от 6 до 10.
    '11-15' : 5 - кол-во уникальных спортсменов у которых максимальный прыжок от 10 до 15.
  }
}
```

Пока у меня получалось только получить максимальный результат для каждого спортсмена, но я не могу понять как его можно ранжировать уровнем выше.

Для примера на SQL это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
SELECT `distace_range`, count(*) FROM (
  SELECT 
    `user_id`,
    IF(MAX(`distace`) <=5, 
      '*-5', 
      IF(MAX(`distace`) >= 6 AND MAX(`distace`) >= 10,
        '6-10',
        '11-15'        
      ) 
    ) `distace_range`
  FROM `events`
  GROUP BY `user_id`
) t
GROUP BY `distace_range;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опубликовал [вопрос](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/topic/39395) на официальном форуме *elasticsearch*.
На данный момент задачу такой выборки не решить штатными средствами для версии *elasticsearch 2.1.х* т.к. для запроса:

```
'aggregations' => [
  'distance_range' => [
    'terms' => [
      'field' => 'doc.user_id',

    ],
    'aggregations' => [
      'max_distance' => [
        'max' => [
          'field' => 'doc.distance'
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

то не хватает *Pipeline* агрегатора по *range* или *term*.

Есть несколько подходов для решения в текущей ситуации:

1. создание дополнительного индекса содержащего максимальный результат
2. использование скриптов
3. просуммировать результат на клиенте

В данный момент я воспользовался 3 вариантом.

Вариант 1 меня не устроил тем, что дополнительный индекс необходимо контролировать, что-бы он был актуален.

Вариант 2 сложность вычисления или влияние на выборку очень сильно влияет на время выборки и дополнительно придется поддерживать код в нескольких системах.

Answer (score 0):

Уточните СУБД.
Если у вас sql server или Oracle, для подсчета количество уникальных спортсменов можно использовать COUNT(DISTINCT):

```
SELECT distance_range, COUNT(DISTINCT "user_id")cnt_unique_users
FROM(
  SELECT "user_id",
    CASE 
      WHEN distance <= 5 THEN '*-5'
      WHEN distance <= 10 THEN '6-10'
      WHEN distance <= 15 THEN '11-15'
      ELSE '16-*'
    END distance_range
  FROM events
)T
GROUP BY distance_range
```

Если не нравится, то DISTINCT можно использовать в подзапросе. Результат будет тем же:

```
SELECT distance_range, COUNT("user_id")cnt_unique_users
FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT "user_id",
    CASE 
      WHEN distance <= 5 THEN '*-5'
      WHEN distance <= 10 THEN '6-10'
      WHEN distance <= 15 THEN '11-15'
      ELSE '16-*'
    END distance_range
  FROM events
)T
GROUP BY distance_range
```

Comment: Elasticsearch. Это было указано в заголовке и тегах. Поправил что-бы не возникало неоднозначности. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Ага, не увидел. Последний пример написан в синтаксисе SQL-92, должен работать.

Comment: К сожалению, @pegoopik, ваш ответ не поможет т.к. _elastickseach_ не поддерживает _SQL_ синтаксис.